# Effects on net Electric Potential with the insertion of a dielectric into a network of two capacitors in series?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, capacitance, dielectric

Suppose you have a circuit with two capacitors of equal capacitance C, C1 and C2 that remain connected to a battery at all times. A dielectric is then fully inserted between the plates of C1. What, if any, are the effects of the insertion of the dielectric on the net electric potential?

Since the battery remains connected, I assume there is not change in the electric potential of C1, but wouldn't the electric potential on C2 increases by a factor of K since the charge Q on C2 increased by a factor of K (charge of C1 would increase and since they are in series, charge of C2 must also increase) and Capacitance remained unchanged because the electric potential and charge must adjust to keep their ratio constant?

The part where I'm really struggling is deciding if the electric potential must remain constant like that of C1 because it is plugged in, or if the fact that it does change throws everything off. Please help, I keep going around in circles.

Comment: I should clarify that K is dielectric constant and not the K you'd use in Coulomb's Law.